# Circuit with switching

Tags: mosfet, fpga, debugging

CONFIDENTAL CIRCUIT

I'm experiencing some weird behavior though that I don't understand.

1. When I send from FPGA 1 V to turn it on it doesn't working
2. I deliberately chose NMOS with low Vgs voltage.

I think the issue is when I write from FPGA 1 V the NMOS working for us and afterwards it close because the Vgs become negative again(before Vgs=1 V and after it works Vgs=-4 V)

Do you have some idea how to fix it without redesign?

Comment: Please don't remove essential context from your question; I've reverted it to what it was.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without the schematic. VTC for "Needs details or clarity"

Comment: Just so you know, anyone can look at the edit history of this question and see the circuit. If you need past edits to be redacted, you can ask an admin to do that.

Comment: Sorry is confidential circuit, I don't know it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your MOSFET arranged as a source follower and this means that for the device to be just about activated on a light load, the gate must be maybe 1 volt higher than the source: -

[image]

[Data sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN1053UCP4.pdf)

But, given that your drive level is only 1 volt, your source is unlikely to produce any significant voltage that can be used to enable or disable the "other device". Remember, for a source follower, the source will not be a higher voltage than the gate and, it may be a volt or more lower. This is your problem.

> *I deliberately chose NMOS with low VGS voltage.*

Yes, that was the right thing to do but, it's a source follower circuit you have implemented.

> *Do you have some idea how to fix it without redesign?*

It needs redesign in some form or another....

- You could use the MOSFET in common source mode but, you will get signal inversion.
- Then, if you have the space, you could add an inverter to feed the correct logic level to the "other device".
- Alternatively, you could amplify the 1 volt with an op-amp to produce maybe 4 or 5 volts i.e. enough to suit the logic level of the "other device".

Comment: I Measured on the source 0.7V , where is it come from? it is not signal inversion.

Comment: Leakage current through the channel. But, does your comment have anything to do with your original question?

Comment: I need to fix it , some creative idea or I need to do layout fix and send it again to production please need help

Comment: If you can't invert the FPGA signal then you can't use the MOSFET in common-source mode so, it doesn't look like you have any options other than to use an extra inverter after you have put the MOSFET in common source. I guess you could use an op-amp to amplify the 1 volt signal to that needed to enable/disable the "other device" but, if timing is critical then this will also have problems.

Comment: My bad. the 1V voltage is from dc/dc supply voltage. its not from FPGA, maybe you have some other idea?

Comment: @Knowledge I have no idea what your last comment should be taken to mean. If you are saying that the 1 volt comes from a 1 volt supply then you have fewer options because you cannot invert it. Hence, either use an op-amp or use the MOSFET in common-source followed by an inverter. Are we done here now? I believe your question is answered and, remember that this site is not a talking shop; it's a Q and A  showcase site.

Comment: sorry but you are not solve my problem, this nmos used as a switch, don't understand what your mean source follower, its not was my choice.

Comment: @Knowledge I have answered your question; I have told you why the MOSFET used in its current configuration will not work and I have offered alternative solutions. The MOSFET can only be used as a switch if the gate voltage exceeds the drain voltage (5 volts) by at least 1 volt. This will not happen with a source follower (common-drain) MOSFET because the source will always be lower than the gate by 1 volt for this particular MOSFET. If you were hoping for a magic solution then this isn't going to happen; the circuit is flawed and needs redesign.

Comment: @Knowledge - "sorry but you are not solve my problem, this nmos used as a switch" Andy's point is that the FET is not being used as a switch. It is being used as a follower. And that's why it's not working.

Comment: if the vgs will be 1.5v it will work?

Comment: @Knowledge it will not work with any NMOSFET connected as a source follower irrespective of Vgs threshold voltage; the configuration is wrong; source followers do not amplify and you want amplification of 1 volt to something possibly above 3 volts. That will not happen with a source follower. You need amplification.

Answer (score 3):

Although Andy aka has answered your question, and you have selected his answer, you continue (in comment) to ask for suggestions. The answer is fairly simple - you need to change your approach. The first step is to configure your FET as a switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc2JCz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now 1 volt at the gate is 1 volt from gate to source, and the FET will operate as you intended. However, you will probably object that this won't work, since it will produce 0 volts for a 1-volt input, rather than the 5 volts you want. That's not hard to overcome.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjbqla.png)</sup>

Your new p-type FET must also be a logic-level part, but it operates with a gate voltage swing of 5 volts, rather than 1.

In many ways you'd be better off simply finding a single-supply 5 volt comparator and do

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWsEE2.png)</sup>